# Does Google offer a service where you can post an html page for a wiki?

Tags: google-sites

I want to share an HTML page for the team in the company where I work, part of which is outsourced. Instead of making a webpage for it, is there a Google service where we could upload the html?

Comment: Is this on-topic for SO? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this service : https://sites.google.com

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of https://sites.google.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/)? It seems to fit your needs.